# Is rendered id of aspx control always rendered the same in source html code?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

For Eg i have an aspx textbox with `id="txtkms"`
In html view source i can see that it is being rendered as `ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtkms_1`
My question is .. this control `txtkms` always be rendered as `ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtkms_1` everytime i run my aspx page on any browser or any other computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDs generated for controls actually depends on your defined settings only OR if you haven't specified any , then on Default settings applicable.

Depending on what you set for **[`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx)** property for pages/controls, Control IDs can be exactly the same that you put in your markup, or may append the IDs of your naming containers separated by an underscore character (_).

For example, when you set `ClientIDMode="Static"`, The **[`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)** value is set to the value of the `ID` property you set in your Markup.

[ ClientID is the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET ]

Also, when you set `ClientIDMode="AutoID"`, The **[`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)** value is generated by concatenating the `ID` values of each parent naming container with the `ID` value of the control.  Also, In data-binding scenarios( Such as repeater, GridView..)  where multiple instances of a control are rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's `ID` value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_).

***The default value of `ClientIDMode` for a page is `Predictable`. The default value of `ClientIDMode` for a control is `Inherit`.***

Check ***[this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)***. Also, check ***[this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature)*** for more details.

Comment: I havent specified any ClientIDMode property for the page or the cotnrols in Gridview. I am getting `ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtkms_0 ` for `txtkms` with incrementing value ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtkms_1 ..2...3 and so on. Now.. i am using these rendred ids of first 5 rows. 
Please my previous question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/18973570/2064292

Comment: This is an expected behaviour. You haven't specified anything means the Default settings will be used. If you haven't specified anything, it doesn't means NO settings apply at all. The Default settings will be applicable in such cases.Default for controls is Inherit, the default generation mode is Predictable for controls in Databound Controls as happening above.The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ClientID value of the parent naming container with the ID value of the control with underscore characters. Check the MSDN link Provided in my answer

Comment: Ok, i understand what you are saying.. now that the cliendidmode is predictable in my case... i am assuming that its always going to render `txtkms` to `ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtkms_0 ..1..2..3` and so on of that particular page and GridView on every browser on any computer right? Is it possible that it would be rendered something other than `ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtkms_0..1..2` in my case?

Comment: 1.)  Yes you are right.  2.) If you want you can set ClientIDMOde to static for your GridView.But in DataBound controls it is not recommended to do this as many controls in different row will have same ID then. Also, the suffixes you see, _0..1..2 etc are controlled by ClientIdRowSuffix property. if you want you can set suffix property to any of your Column names, so Column values will be appended at end rather than numeric values like 0,1,2.  when accessing controls at client side in Javascript, use ClientID property,in code behind you access the control names by using the ID values only.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen it change, but it's safer to pass the ClientID to the javascript where you'll be using it...

Comment: Is it possible to pass the ClientId of a textbox in a gridview and ClientId of another textbox in the same row to javascript function?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtrateperkm" runat="server"   OnBlur="calc(x,y,z)"></asp:TextBox>
a=id of this control
b=is value of this control(i think clac(this.value) will work)
c=Id of of a specific control in same row of gridView.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you set ClientIdMode=Static in your web config.

You can even use this:

You can use the jQuery ends with selector:

$('input[id$="myServerId"]')

But remember, that kind of selector is a lot slower than selecting directly with the id with <%= id.ClientID %>.

http://jsperf.com/id-vs-ends-with

This solution came from Gromer:

[What's the best way to deal with ASP.NET's ClientID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614042/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-asp-nets-clientid)